# Load chart data into a webapp from google datastore

Tags: python, wordpress, google-app-engine, charts, google-cloud-datastore

I've got a google app engine application that loads time series data real-time into a google datastore nosql style table. I was hoping to get some feedback around the right type of architecture to pull this data into a web application style chart (and ideally something I could also plug into a content management system like Word Press).

Most of my server-side code is python. What's a reasonable client-server setup to pull the data from the datastore database and display into my webpage? Ideally I'd have something that scales and doesn't cause an unnecessary number of reads on my database (potentially using google-app-engine's built in caching/etc).

I'm guessing this is a common use-case but I'd like to get an idea of what might be some best practices around this. I've seen some examples using client web side javascript/ajax with server side php to read the DB- is this really the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to "it depends".

You have some choices. Imagine the classic four-quadrant chart. Along one axis is data size, along the other is staleness/freshness.

If your time-series data changes rapidly but is small enough to safely be retrieved within a request, you can query for it on demand, convert it to JSON, and squirt it to the browser to be rendered by the JavaScript charting package of your choice. If the data is large, your app will need to do some sort of server-side pre-processing so that when the data is needed, it can be retrieved in sufficiently fewer requests that that the request won't time out. This might involve something data dependent like pre-bucketing the time series.

If the data changes slowly, you have the option of generating your chart on the server side, perhaps using `matplotlib`. When new data is ingested, or perhaps at intervals, spawn off a task to generate and cache the chart (or JSON to hand to the front-end) as a blob in the datastore. If the data is sufficiently large that a task will timeout, you might need to use a backend process. If the data is sufficiently large and you don't pre-process, you're in the quadrant of unhappiness.

In my experience, GAE memcache is best for caching data between requests where the time between requests is very short. Don't rely on generating artifacts, stuff them in memcache and hoping that they'll be there a few minutes later. I've rarely seen that work.